# Declare Http body in routes file play2Framework

Tags: java, scala, rest, playframework-2.0

I can not find way to declare http body of request in routs.

Is it possible to declare http body in routes file in play2framework (possible it's scala feature :/)?

I have declaration in routes:

```
POST   /adt/api/auth/login   @com.test.security.ApplicationAuthController.login()
```

and implementation like this:

```
    public Promise<Result> login() {
            LoginRequest loginRequest = RequestHelper.validateAndGetRequest(LoginRequest.class);
            ...
    }
```

But I'd like to declare http body something like jax-rs do.

routes:

```
POST   /adt/api/auth/login   @com.test.security.ApplicationAuthController.login(requets: LoginRequest)
```

and implementation:

```
    public Promise<Result> login(LoginRequest requets) {
            ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I work with Play-Scala so I might be wrong here but I believe you don't need to specify it in routes anywhere. You can access the current request directly using `request()` static method in `play.mvc.Controller` like this

```
public Promise<Result> login() {
    Http.Request currentRequest = play.mvc.Controller.request();
    return play.mvc.Results.ok("Request received: " + currentRequest);
}
```

Comment: I do this in my RequestHelper. But I'd like to write body validator before accessing method. It's overhead to write play.mvc.Controller.request() in each controller method when it's POST.